# Could not get link from html content using python

Tags: python, web-scraping, urllib2, urllib

Here is the URL that I'am using:

http://www.protect-stream.com/PS_DL_xODN4o5HjLuqzEX5fRNuhtobXnvL9SeiyYcPLcqaqqXayD8YaIvg9Qo80hvgj4vCQkY95XB7iqcL4aF1YC8HRg_i_i

In fact on this page, the link that I am looking for appears may be 5 second after loading the page.

I see after 5 second a post request to :
http://www.protect-stream.com/secur.php
with data like so :

```
k=2AE_a,LHmb6kSC_c,sZNk4eNixIiPo_c,_c,Gw4ERVdriKuHJlciB1uuy_c,Sr7mOTQVUhVEcMlZeINICKegtzYsseabOlrDb_a,LmiP80NGUvAbK1xhbZGC6OWMtIaNF12f0mYA4O0WxBkmAtz75kpYcrHzxtYt32hCYSp0WjqOQR9bY_a,ofQtw_b,
```

I didn't get from where the 'k' value come from ?

Is their an idea on how we could get the 'k' value using python ?

Answer (score 1):

This is not going to be trivial. The `k` parameter value is "hidden" deep inside a `script` element inside nested iframes. Here is a [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) + [`BeautifulSoup`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) way to get to the `k` value:

```
import re
from urlparse import urljoin
# Python 3: from urllib.parse import urljoin

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

base_url = "http://www.protect-stream.com"
with requests.Session() as session:
    response = session.get("http://www.protect-stream.com/PS_DL_xODN4o5HjLuqzEX5fRNuhtobXnvL9SeiyYcPLcqaqqXayD8YaIvg9Qo80hvgj4vCQkY95XB7iqcL4aF1YC8HRg_i_i")

    # get the top frame url
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
    src = soup.select_one('iframe[src^="frame.php"]')["src"]
    frame_url = urljoin(base_url, src)

    # get the nested frame url
    response = session.get(frame_url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
    src = soup.select_one('iframe[src^="w.php"]')["src"]
    frame_url = urljoin(base_url, src)

    # get the frame HTML source and extract the "k" value
    response = session.get(frame_url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
    script = soup.find("script", text=lambda text: text and "k=" in text).get_text(strip=True)

    k_value = re.search(r'var k="(.*?)";', script).group(1)
    print(k_value)
```

Prints:

```
YjfH9430zztSYgf7ItQJ4grv2cvH3mT7xGwv32rTy2HiB1uuy_c,Sr7mOTQVUhVEcMlZeINICKegtzYsseabOlrDb_a,LmiP80NGUvAbK1xhbZGC6OWMtIaNF12f0mYA4O0WXhmwUC0ipkPRkLQepYHLyF1U0xvsrzHMcK2XBCeY3_a,O_b,
```